# How come, I don't have permission to list profiles If I have fullAccess?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have logged into my AWS Management Console as a regular user, which already has `AmazonEC2FullAccess`

But while launching EC2 instance it says:

> You do not have permissions to list instance profiles. Contact your administrator, or check your IAM permissions.

[image]

How come, I don't have permission to list profiles If I have fullAccess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have access to view this you would also need to have IAM permissions to be able to list the roles that exist.

`AmazonEC2FullAccess` does not cover this permission.

Ensure you have the following permission attached to your IAM user `iam:ListInstanceProfiles`.

There is a policy for IAMReadOnlyAccess which will grant that, but it also allows the listing of other IAM resources

Comment: So do I need to `Create policy` ? Or is there any `managed policies` for this purpose?

Comment: There is a policy for `IAMReadOnlyAccess` which will grant that, but it also allows the listing of other IAM resources

Comment: Where to add `iam:ListInstanceProfiles`?

Comment: If explicitly only that permission then create a policy and attach it :)